# what $ ,^ and * symbols are doing in python 2.7 and BS4

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

In the [Selenium Doc](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) they have used `^`, `$` and `*` previous to the `=` operators the in the below code: But none of them are explained why such **special symbols**

```
soup.select('a[href="http://example.com/elsie"]')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>]

soup.select('a[href^="http://example.com/"]')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
#  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]

soup.select('a[href$="tillie"]')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]

soup.select('a[href*=".com/el"]')
# [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those are [substring matching attribute selectors adapted from CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings):

- `=` matches only if the given value is *equal* to the element’s attribute value.
- `^=` matches only if the given value is *a prefix* of the element’s attribute value.
- `$=` matches only if the given value is *a suffix* of the element’s attribute value.
- `*=` matches only if the given value is *contained* in the element’s attribute value.

In your case:

- `a[href="http://example.com/elsie"]` selects any `a` element whose `href` attribute value is equal to `http://example.com/elsie`.
- `a[href^="http://example.com/"]` selects any `a` element whose `href` attribute value starts with `http://example.com/`.
- `a[href$="tillie"]` selects any `a` element whose `href` attribute value ends with `tillie`.
- `a[href*=".com/el"]` selects any `a` element whose `href` attribute value contains `.com/el`.

Comment: that link is not opening in my desktop. can you tell me in my example what it does?

Comment: Ohh!! God it opened!! got the concept! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can I have some idea on the [Push data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171223/push-the-excel-data-to-access-database-using-pyhton2-7#comment19636110_14171223)

Answer (score 3):

What you see are CSS selectors:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors